# gtkmm: Are some default singals set, and how do I over-ride them?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

Note: I have decided to split this question into 2 questions, the second of which will be linked from here shortly.

I have just started programming with gtkmm.

I have opened a window and put a TextView object in the window.

I can type text into the textview, and I can also copy and paste it.

- I want to map CTRL-C and CTRL-V to custom actions for the textview. Is it possible to do this?

I also notice that ALT-F4 closes the window, as does clicking the X in the window titlebar.

- I assume that there is some default code which comes with a "window" or a "textview" to allow default behaviour such as CTRL-C, CTRL-V, ALT-F4, etc. Is my assumption correct and if so where is this code "hidden away", and is it possible for me to modify it?

I guess this question might be tricky to conceptualize, so I will explain what I am trying to do.

I am trying to write my own version of a text editor, based on gedit/emacs/vim. In order to do this I have started working with the GTK toolkit gtkmm.

I am not completely sure that this is a wise choice, and so I have posted a second question regarding this, however hopefully those who are familiar with vim/emacs will have some idea as to why I am trying to re-map certain key combinations for my own use.

Comment: Does googling for _gtkmm default signal handler_ not find anything for you? It looks promising when I try it.

Comment: @underscore_d From this https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-overriding-default-signal-handlers.html.en it looks like one can over-ride methods using inheritance. But what about completely disabling behaviour? Also where would I find information about what other things are implemented by default?

Comment: Disabling behaviour would be done by overriding the default handler to do nothing. Overidding a handler can be done either by inheritance or - in my opinion, preferably - by simply connecting another handler, with the argument `bool after = false` if required, and returning `true` to block other handlers. This is general to GObject signals, not specific to GTK+ or `gtkmm`. As for what behaviour exists by default, that's really a function of GTK+, not `gtkmm` specifically, so maybe best to check there, although `gtkmm` should import most of the pertinent info from the GTK+ docs.

Comment: @underscore_d Ok that's quite interesting. So essentially I would have to make a new class for every object that I wanted my own custom behaviour for, inheriting from the relevant classes, and over-riding all signals code. This seems somewhat inefficient however. I guess an alternative (not sure about the feasability of this) would be to copy all relevant classes, change the names and delete the default signals if I can find "where they are wired up"? I guess I would have to compile the GTKmm libs again for myself however.

Comment: _"I would have to make a new class for every object that I wanted my own custom behaviour for"_ Absolutely not. That's why I specifically said _"Overriding a handler can be done either by inheritance or - in my opinion, preferably - by simply connecting another handler"_, i.e. to any instance of the standard class. Also, copying and modifying all the classes... please, no. You don't need any such complications; you can simply connect the signals you want to the instances you want, at the before/after point you want. Only rarely will there be a need to use inheritance to change signal behaviour

Comment: I am confident that the `gtkmm` documentation will contain multiple examples show how to do what you want to do. If you think it doesn't, post a specific question about a specific scenario, and users can advise.

Comment: @underscore_d I actually think this is going in the wrong direction, in regards to keyboard events. When it comes to keyboard events the question is still open as to how the default ones are set up: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-keyboardevents-overview.html.en#keyboardevents-simple-example